# access to assembly configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

Assembly configuration file (Program.config) created under administrator account. When I switch to user account (not administrator), I cannot write configuration section to this file. Specifically, code looks like this:

```
//creating section (and file) with administrator access
UserInfoConfigurationSection user_conf = new UserInfoConfigurationSection();
Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
conf.Sections.Add("userInfo", user_conf);
conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);


//trying to write to section under user account
Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
UserInfoConfigurationSection user_conf = (UserInfoConfigurationSection)conf.Sections["userInfo"];
user_conf.SerialKey = textBoxSerial.Text;
user_conf.UserCompany = textBoxCompany.Text;
user_conf.UserName = textBoxUser.Text;
conf.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);//getting exception
```

What is the best option to write and read settings under any account?

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job and create the settings you want to be changed at runtime with the user scope: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#settingscs_topic2

Comment: It does not work (Properties.Settings.Default.SomeSetting). Values written under one account inaccessible under another. Those are user-scope settings, but I need read and write the same values under different accounts.

Comment: Please explain the reasons for this, so we can suggest the right way to do it.